# Cannot access the shared folder

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares, shared-folders

There is a shared drive in our university where anyone can share files. I had mapped this as a network drive on my computer earlier but cannot access it anymore. I am using Windows 7.

When I put the given IP (`\\10.3.20.20`) in run command, it says `Windows cannot access \\10.3.20.20` with the **Error code: 0x80070035**

Success

1. Everyone else can open it easily
2. I can **ping** it
3. I can open it in **WinSCP**
4. `net view \\10.3.20.20` works fine (shows `Samba Server Version 3.0.33-3.7.el5`) and gives the list of all folders in it
5. I can open it from Windows XP installation from the same computer
6. My browser works fine

Error

1. `net use \\10.3.20.20` returns `System error 53 has occurred.`
2. Tried opening this from run
3. Tried opening it in explorer
4. I tried to map the network to a drive I got the same error message.
5. Tried accessing a folder on this location
6. I have turned off my firewall and anti-virus, this didn't help.

I live in a hostel, onsite of a university campus, and I'm trying to connect to my uni computer from the hostel. It is here where it fails. I cannot connect to the shared folders on my own workstation within the university from the hostel!

I can RDP into the workstation.

Comment: No I cannot open the IP from the explorer (run), how can I map a folder?

Comment: No, it gave the same error as it did with run

Comment: Turned off firewall, Turned off Real Time protection of Security Essentials. Still getting the same error

Comment: As was able to map the drive and access it earlier, some service might not be working. But Computer Browser, Tcp ip/bios, Network, DHCP services are running fine.

Comment: The shared folder is there, everyone can access it. Only I am getting this error. This is a Wireless LAN. I have edited to make my problems clear. Can you please edit and make it more clear.

Comment: We connect on wireless lan and there are many wireless networks available. Even if we are on the same network, we cannot ping each other as I just tried with a friend. No ping, no shared access. We are assigned a new IP each time we connect with a network.
I have computer in Lab which I can connect with remote desktop. I shared a folder on it but can not access it from this computer.

Comment: Also I can still connect to 10.3.20.20 from my pc in Lab (I am in hostel)

Comment: Is it possible that the system administrator has altered something? Can you just double check that your friend can still access too?

Comment: What do you mean *Also I can still connect to 10.3.20.20 from my pc in Lab (I am in hostel)*? Also, it may be a good idea to delete some of your comments as I have moved them into the question for you

Comment: And lastly, do you only have an IP address, do you have a name of the server which you could try and connect to?

Comment: I live in hostel (inside university) and I have a PC in computer lab to which I connect from hostel. That PC is connected to that shared drive. Hosts file is in its original form. My IP is dynamic, and the shared location we connect to is not named perhaps.

Comment: I also have problem with some windows updates. KB2724197, KB2676562 and KB2679255 are not installing. They give the error code 800B0100. That might have been causing this problem

Comment: The one in hostel.

Comment: No no, I can not access the shared folders of that lab computer. Althogh I can connect to it with remote desktop.

Comment: I have admin access to that system. I shared a folder from that system by connecting to it but cannot access from hostel. I am strongly thinking that those updates are part of this issue. I am trying to solve that.

Comment: Please try this tool: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/What-is-the-System-Update-Readiness-Tool

Comment: Or this tool, which will try and automatically [fix the issue from Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/C/9/6C970550-32AB-4235-9CDD-7FC9DD848BBB/windowsupdate.diagcab)

Comment: I am already trying all these. And other fixes from microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

I have done some research and this article looks the most promising. I've copied the relevant part over.

> Browse to "Local Policies" -> "Security Options".  Now look for the
>   entry "Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level" and open
>   it.  Click on the dropdown menu and select "Send LM & NTLM - use
>   NTLMv2 session security if negotiated".  Apply the settings.
>
> In the Advanced sharing settings page of Network and sharing center,
>   you need to have it set as Work/Home profile.  Try:
>
> -Enable network discovery
>   -Turn on  file and print sharing
>   -Turn off password protected sharing
>   -Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers
>
> The other settings such as encryption I have set as use 128 bit
>   encryption.
>
> Please check related policies.
>
> 1. Enter “gpedit.msc” in the Start Search box.
> 2. Open “Computer Configuration”/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Settings.
> 3. In the right pane, enable the following policies:
>
> Network access: Allow anonymous SID/name translation Network access:
>   Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users
>
> Also please disable the following policies.
>
> Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares
>   Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts
>   Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and
>   shares

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/68ffbe2a-09a7-4e29-859c-ca1aaf75dcd1)

Comment: I restarted the PC and still getting the same error. :-( Only browsing with explorer is not working, otherwise that network address is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as requiring a second backslash?

"Windows cannot access \10.3.20.20" with the Error code: 0x80070035
I would try:

```
\\10.3.20.20
```

Here is more of my research on [error 80070035](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/code/code_80070035.htm)

Comment: Guy, this wasn't the case, the OP was just formatted badly (if you type \\ without the blockquote or code tag on the SU site it will format it and automatically remove one of the slashes. I have edited the OP and corrected it now.